# Creating Vote/Survey SMS like first multi-step SMS sending

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile

We are trying to send a Vote/Survey like first multi-step SMS, via AtomationStudio, but we haven´t found the way to do that.
The only way we have found, is to send first an Outbound SMS (it can send by automation method), but we need to send the Vote/Survey at first, without the outbound SMS.

Do you know the way to do that?

Thenk you

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had to perform the same task.

I built two separate mobile messages, and tied them together using the "next" keyword.

**Message 1 - Outbound - No Keyword - Next Keyword = "Vote"** *(sample message only)*

- Outbound Message - Please take our survey - respond with Y or N

**Message 2 - Vote/Survey - Keyword "Vote"** *(sample message only)*

- No outbound message.
- Response Y - Thank you for voting Yes.
- Respone N - Thank you for voting No.

The "next" keyword functionality on the outbound message will automatically call "[Next Keyword] " + response from outbound message.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is the way we found.

Comment: We need to send a non aoutbound survey message without the first outbound.